# How to activate Opengl 4 for AMD graphic cards in Ubuntu/Linux Mint?

Tags: amd-graphics

I have a AMD RX460. I use Linux Mint 18 and Kernel 4.8 and Xubuntu 16.04 with Kernel 4.10.

In Linux Mint I have installed the private drivers of AMD for this card and in Xubuntu I use the Open Source Drivers (use

The problem is that the Open Source drivers don't use Opengl 4, only Opengl 3 and I think this card cans support the AMDGPU open drivers with Opengl 4 but I cannot activate them.

Can you help me to activate them?

Comment: If the proprietary drivers don't work yet with the 4.10 kernel there's nothing we can do but wait for AMD to provide updates. A newer version of the open source driver may or may not give support for OpenGL 4.x (which is a function of both the hardware and software (drivers)).

Comment: Hi, the propiertary driver Works with Opengl 4.5 and kernel 4.8. I ask if the open source drivers can Works with Opengl 4 in any way.

Comment: You already know the answer: No, not yet anyway.

Comment: Hi; I updated Xubuntu 16.04 and uninstalled the AMDGPU-PRO, I don't know what changed in the Kernel 10 but the Open Source drivers (AMDGPU) are working with Opengl 4.5. I check with Metro 2033 and the game runs softly (30 stable FPS) but loads game is more slowly than AMDGPU-PRO.

Linux Mint Sonya seems incompatible with Kernel 10 and I cannot use the new AMDGPU, cotinue using Kernel 4.8 and AMDGPU-PRO drivers.

Comment: Linux Mint 18.2 is compatible with 4.10 and even 4.11, open the Software Update tool, in the View menu go to Kernel and you can install 4.11 there.